# Argument until non-alphanumeric character

Tags: macros, active-characters

Not sure if this is possible or not...

I would like to turn (say) `+` into a command with one argument without braces. This argument should be everything following the `+` *up until the first non-alphanumeric character*. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`+\active

\def+{%
  %do some magic tricks
}

\begin{document}

+ % + with an empty argument
+hello527world % + with the argument hello527world
+cool. This is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by ". This is nice."
+cool is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by a space and "is nice"

\end{document}
```

In other words, `+` should work a bit like `\`, just with support for alphanumeric characters. Also, following spaces are to be typed out.

Why in the world do I want this? I'm trying to create a simpler front-end to LaTeX, and I would like to use the `+blahblah` notation for citations.

I tried playing around with `xparse`, but I didn't find any way to accomplish exactly this.

Comment: It seems to be possible, put do I advise it? *No*

Comment: The old `amslatex` had an `\atdef@` command that made macros prefixed by `@` instead of the backslash (it's still used in `amscd.sty`). Setting `+` as an active character is a very bad idea, though, because it's syntactically meaningful.

Comment: “Up to the first non-alphanumeric character”?  It would be (a little bit) simpler it it were “up to the first non-letter character”, _i.e._, a condition that could be tested with `\ifcat`.

Comment: Or, is it permissible to depend on pdftex and its `\pdfmatch` primitive?

Comment: Solutions with non-letter characters are welcome, so are solutions that rely on pdfTeX. If necesssary, a LuaTeX solution will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from one of the comments: “Solutions with non-letter characters are welcome”.  So, I present a solution that extracts arguments made entirely of letter (`\catcode` = 11) characters, up to, but not including, the first non-letter.  In principle, the code could be adapted to include the ten digits 0…9 as well.

This solution requires nothing more than the original TeX by Knuth.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter

% Avoid using a critical character like +
\catcode`\! = \active
\def!{%
  \toks@{}%
  \@AN@scan@forward
}
\@ifdefinable\@AN@scan@forward{\def\@AN@scan@forward{%
  \futurelet\next \@AN@test@next
}}
\@ifdefinable\@AN@test@next{\def\@AN@test@next{%
  \ifcat A\noexpand\next
    \expandafter\@AN@add@token
  \else
    \expandafter\@AN@call@payload
  \fi
}}
\@ifdefinable\@AN@add@token{\def\@AN@add@token#1{%
  \toks@ \expandafter{\the\toks@ #1}%
  \@AN@scan@forward
}}
\@ifdefinable\@AN@call@payload{\def\@AN@call@payload{%
  \ANPayload{\the\toks@}%
  % (Or
  % \expandafter\ANPayload \expandafter{\the\toks@}%
  % if needed).
}}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\ANPayload}[1]{%
  % Substitute the operations you want to perform on the argument:
  \typeout{#1}%
  \textbf{#1}%
}



\begin{document}

Reference text.
! % + with an empty argument
!hello527world % + with the argument hello followed by "527world"
!helloworld % + with the argument helloworld
!cool. This is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by ". This is nice."
!cool is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by a space and "is nice"

\end{document}
```

[image]

I must warn the, probably, *xparse* provides better solutions, which I simply don’t know: I resolved to post this provisional answer after seeing that no other answer had been provided for about two days.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what half of those commands mean, but thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I made a library...

```tex
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythonimmediate}

\begin{pycode}
```

```python
from pythonimmediate import newcommand, peek_next_char, get_next_char
from pythonimmediate import print as print_to_TeX
from string import ascii_letters, digits
@newcommand
def plussign():
    s=""
    while True:
        ch=peek_next_char()
        if ch!="" and (ch in ascii_letters or ch in digits):
            get_next_char()
            s+=ch
        else:
            break
    print_to_TeX(r'(' + s + ')', end="")  # need end="" to suppress the new line character being interpreted as a space, see documentation for details (did I remember to include it in the documentation?)
```

```tex
\end{pycode}

% currently there's no function to define active character yet...
\catcode `+\active
\let+\plussign

\begin{document}


+ % + with an empty argument

+hello527world % + with the argument hello527world

+cool. This is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by ". This is nice."

+cool is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by a space and "is nice"

\end{document}
```

Output is as you expect:

[image: output]

---

That having said, this is a "normal" implementation:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__gaussler_plus_sign:n #1 {
    (#1)
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__gaussler_plus_sign:w {
    \peek_regex_replace_once:nn {[A-Za-z0-9]*} {\c{__gaussler_plus_sign:n}{\0}}
}
\char_set_active_eq:NN + \__gaussler_plus_sign:w
\char_set_catcode_active:N +
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}


+ % + with an empty argument

+hello527world % + with the argument hello527world

+cool. This is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by ". This is nice."

+cool is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by a space and "is nice"

\end{document}
```

All the magic is hidden behind the `\peek_regex_replace_once:nn` function. Basically it replaces e.g. the token list `cool. This is nice`
with `\__gaussler_plus_sign:n {cool}. This is nice.`, then the function itself do the work. (in this example it wraps a pair of parentheses around it)

Comment: (Not that the OP needs this anymore, I just come across the question now)

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `\peek_regex_replace_once:nn`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\+}{}
 {
  \gaussler_plus:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \gaussler_plus:
 {
  \peek_regex_replace_once:nn { ([[:alnum:]]*) } { \c{gaussler_plus_do:n}\cB\{\1\cE\} }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \gaussler_plus_do:n
 {
  --Argument~was~|#1|--
 }

% if you want to live dangerously
\char_gset_active_eq:NN + \gaussler_plus:
\char_set_catcode_active:N +

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\+ % + with an empty argument

\+Hello527World % + with the argument hello527world

\+cool. This is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by ". This is nice."

\+cool is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by a space and "is nice"

+ % + with an empty argument

+Hello527World % + with the argument hello527world

+cool. This is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by ". This is nice."

+cool is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by a space and "is nice"

\end{document}
```

The tokens matching the search regex (first argument) are replaced as directed by the replacement regex (second argument). Here they are fed as argument to `\gaussler_plus:n`.

I also show how to make `+` active. It's not a good idea, because the standard `+` with catcode 12 is part of TeX's syntax for numbers.

[image]

You can make a variant where no alphanumeric following character triggers some other action.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\+}{}
 {
  \gaussler_plus:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \gaussler_plus:
 {
  \peek_regex_replace_once:nnF 
   { ([[:alnum:]]+) } % search
   { \c{gaussler_plus_do:n}\cB\{\1\cE\} } % replace
   { Hey! } % no match
 }
\cs_new:Nn \gaussler_plus_do:n
 {
  --Argument~was~|#1|--
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\+ % + with an empty argument

\+Hello527World % + with the argument hello527world

\+cool. This is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by ". This is nice."

\+cool is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by a space and "is nice"

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another variant where initial spaces are ignored so long as an alphanumeric follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\+}{}
 {
  \gaussler_plus:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \gaussler_plus:
 {
  \peek_regex_replace_once:nnF 
   { \s*([[:alnum:]]+) } % search
   { \c{gaussler_plus_do:n}\cB\{\1\cE\} } % replace
   { Hey! } % no match
 }
\cs_new:Nn \gaussler_plus_do:n
 {
  --Argument~was~|#1|--
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\+ % + with an empty argument

\+ Hello527World % + with the argument hello527world

\+cool. This is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by ". This is nice."

\+ cool is nice. % + with the argument cool followed by a space and "is nice"

\end{document}
```

Same output as before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But of all your 10ⁿ answers for *n* → ∞, why did you choose to make *this* one a community wiki? `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler Because I realized that part of it was already in another answer.